# How can racket run from the CMD

Tags: racket

I am trying to run racket form the command prompt and have the program output go to a textfile.

C:\Downloads>racketprogram.rkt 'run-file > output.txt

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at the [Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/running.html) about running a script or compiling a program?

Basics are that you can call a script with `racket`:

```
racket racketprogram.rkt 'run-file > output.txt
```

It says you can in both Windows and Unix [add lines in the beginning](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/scripts.html) that makes your program able to be run without being an argument to racket executable. In Windows it means you need to call your script racketprogram.bat while in Unix you just have to [make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/a/521955/83681).

It's also possible to [make an executable](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/exe.html). 
A compiled executable runs faster than a script so you get some benefits from it too:

```
raco exe racketprogram.rkt #makes either racketprogram or racketprogram.exe
```

Now the result won't run on a machine that doesn't have exact the same racket version installed so toyou have a different command to make a package with all dependencies. Thus. The result cannot cross OS borders but will be able to run on same OS elsewhere:

```
raco distribute racketprogram-package racketprogram[.exe]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way of running a Racket program I could figure out so far is:

```
racket -l errortrace -t <YOUR SOURCE CODE FILE.rkt>
```

This shows more about errors should they occur.